# I don't understand the reason for this error "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: extended multiple times"

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-wtforms

My layout.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" //Since this is the base template, this will be rendered. This can stay the same for all the html pages
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head><!--creating blocks. Blocks allows our template to change some specific functionality of the base template-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.37.1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% block head %}
    <title>AM Calibration</title> 
    {% endblock %}
    
</head>

<body> <!--By creating the block, the content below is going to be shown in every page-->
    {% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}
    <div class="container">
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</body>

</html>
```

I have extended the layout.html file in several different templates and not errors but when I {% entends "layout.html"%} in the register.html file, I get the "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: extended multiple times"

I have used WTForms to create the registration form.

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', [validators.Length(min=1, max=50)])
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=50)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords do not match')
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')
```

## Routing the registration form to the Home page

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form) #the request function help to bring in the form.
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        return render_template("register.html")
    return render_template("register.html", form=form)  
if __name__== "__main__":
    ##debug=True is a keyword argument that will allows not to rerun the server everytime we make a change. and automatically update the website.
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My register.html file is in the templates folder. This is the Registration form and the _formhelper.html is used here to improve the appearence of the form. It looks like below:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
 <h1>Register</h1>
{% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
 <form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.name, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.email, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.username, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.password, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.confirm, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></p>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the layout template extended by the `navbar` template?

Comment: No. The layout template is not extended by the navbar template.